# Error when trying to install Spotify

Tags: software-installation, spotify

I'm trying to install Spotify but I get this error

[image]

First I added this to the source.list

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Then I did this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F5
sudo apt-get update
```

and finally

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Also I just upgraded to 14.04 from 13.10...

Comment: Did you try install it with -f If it still not working try another repository

Comment: Well, i changed it to us repository and then it worked like charm... :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I' m not sure if i can help you but... are you sure that you have the repository non-free activated?

Active all the repositories from software origins: multiverse & non-free.

If it doesn't help you, try to install these packages separately by `sudo apt-get install` or `sudo aptitude install`

I think you can use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dbus libgconf2-4
```

Comment: I did what "running gherkin" suggested me to, changed my repository source to us and it worked... :)